# obtain the current username using WMI

Tags: c, wmi

I am using Win32_NetworkLoginProfile or Win32_Account to get a list of the users for a system. Call to these objects return a lot of users, some local and some belonging to a domain (if the system is part of a domain).

Is there a way to obtain the current user name using WMI?
If yes, how?

furthermore, using Win32_Account I can check whether the username I am listing is either local or part of a domain. Is there a way to achieve the same for the current user?

The code is in C for Windows XP or newer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to obtain the current user name using WMI?

Use the [`Win32_ComputerSystem.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102.aspx) property. It returns the user name along with the domain name, that is, `Domain\User`. If you want the user name only, simply extract it from this string based on `\`.

> furthermore, using Win32_Account I can check whether the username I am listing is either local or part of a domain. Is there a way to achieve the same for the current user?

Well, you can do something like this:

- Split the `Win32_ComputerSystem.UserName` value by the `\` character to get the domain name and the user name separately.
- Obtain the `Win32_Account` object corresponding to the specified domain and user name. These are the key properties of the `Win32_Account` class, so instead of running generic `SELECT` query, use [`IWbemServices::GetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392109.aspx) to retrieve a specific instance by its path:

  ```
  Win32_Account.Domain="<domain>",Name="<username>"
  ```
- Check the `LocalAccount` property of the obtained `Win32_Account` object.